# PHP laravel object not creating in 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, crud, web-development-server

I have a PHP Laravel CRUD application I made where I am using MVC style. I have controllers views and models. My database migration is made and my table in the database is made with php artisan migrate. I am using php 7.3 and laravel 5.8.
On my create view I go to create a single object in my database and my errors are thrown saying nothing in text box (no input) If I comment out the errors then just I click my submit button and nothing happens nothing is entered into my db. I have looked at many different crud examples and I am not sure why my object isn’t being created. Here is what I have
My env is setup correctly I just don’t get the not creating object.

```
//view create
@section('main')
<section id="section-content" class="text-center">
    <div class="container contentdiv rounded">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="pb-2 mt-4 mb-2 border-bottom clearfix">
                <h2>Create Contact</h2>
            </div>
            <div >
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{route('contacts.index')}}">Back</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="col-md-10 mx-auto">
            @if($errors->any())
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <ul>
                        @foreach($errors->all() as  $error)
                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div><br />
            @endif
        </div> -->
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 mx-auto mt-3">
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('contacts.store') }}">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="txtfn" class="col-sm-3"><b>First Name:</b></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtfn" id="txtfn"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="txtln" class="col-sm-3"><b>Last Name:</b></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtln" id="txtln"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="txtem" class="col-sm-3"><b>Email:</b></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtem" id="txtem"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Contact</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
       //controller
       namespace App\Http\Controllers;
     use App\Contact;
     use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required'
        ]);

        $contact = new Contact([
            'first_name' => $request->get('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $request->get('last_name'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'job_title' => $request->get('job_title'),
            'city' => $request->get('city'),
            'country' => $request->get('country')
        ]);
        $contact->save();
        return redirect('/contacts')->with('success', 'Contact saved!');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $contacts = Contact::all();
        return view('contacts.index', compact('contacts'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('contacts.create');
    }
// model
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contact extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'city',
        'country',
        'job_title'
    ];
}
```

Comment: I put the var dump in the store method
and nothing happened
If I insert a row manually then the row appears in my index and I get can get and show the row with the correct data in my show view. Only I cannot update and create it. I can also delete a record successfully 
like this
$contact = new Contact([
'first_name' => var_dump($request->get('first_name')),

Comment: When i click the submit button on my create view nothing happens
I just get the errors - The first name field is required.
The last name field is required.
The email field is required.
although i already entered all these fields on the text boxes still nothing happens and I get these errors on btn click
If i enter a manual record in the db it shows up in the table of my records. only up CREATE and UPDATE nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your input names do not correspond to the keys you are referencing in your `store()` method:

for example:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtfn" id="txtfn"/>
```

here, your input name is `txtfn`, but in your store method, you are looking for `first_name`.

```
'first_name' => $request->get('first_name')
```

so, `$request->get('first_name')` returns `null` as if you didn't pass any value.

You must make your input names match with the keys you are using in your store method, either by changing input names, or by changing key names.

example:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" />
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I will try that right away
That is what I was thinking I wanted to ask if it was like php GETs
'first_name' => $request->get('txtfn')
but I am pretty sure I tried this and it still didnt save in the database.
although i will try first_name now becasue I have first_name in alot of the variable places across my program just using txtfn once is probably why it didnt work

Comment: It should work the way you mention above, but you must remember to also update your validation references too!  However, it's just much easier to let the names be the same as your model properties.. :-)